# Getting start contributing with pentaho kettle and solve a problem related to that

Tags: eclipse, maven, pentaho, development-environment, kettle

I downloaded pentaho kettle master source code from github and tried to open project with eclipse on linux fedora 28.

I have 2 questions:

1- What are these errors messages when I load  pentaho  project:

```
 Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.pentaho.maven.plugins:license-helper-maven-plugin:1.27:check-license (execution: check-license, phase: validate)
```

This error occurs on almost 100% of pom.xml files.

In this example the file is on aggregate-rows_core/pom.xml

Eclipse gives me some options in order to fix this specific problem, example :

```
3 quick fixes available

 Discover new m2e connectors

 Mark goal check-license as ignored in pom.xml

 Mark goal check-license as ignored in eclipse preferences
```

I have already installed Maven 3.

What is these errors and what a I need to deal with it

2- I would like to know where can I find how pentaho kettle works internally in order to understand it and maybe contribute with it. I have for example a problem to report and I would like try to fix it.

thanks.

Comment: Not all maven plugins covered by eclipse lifecycle. This is normal. "Mark goal check-license as ignored in eclipse preferences" and so on. Most probably those plugins are for ci to inject license agreement.  Glad to see pentaho kettle eventually is moved to maven from ivy.

Comment: Details in here. https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html